# APEX : Passing value to Modal page, setting to Null, Submitting causing problem

Tags: dynamic, oracle-apex, action

Looking for a bit of help.

Here is the situation :

I have an interactive grid on P10.
I set a hidden P10 item value from various cells dynamically using a Click dynamic action.
When I unhide the value I can see the action is working and the item is being set correctly.

I have an EDIT button (Behaviour is redirect to page P20) is pressed a modal page (P20) opens with a Static Items region, this modal page has a Pre Rendering action which populates the items using a database query which looks at the P10 hidden item value

I have a 2nd button, NEW, Behaviour is "Defined by Dynamic Action".
When this is pressed I have a dynamic action which sets the hidden P10 item to Null
and I programmatically open P20 using the eval command.

In both cases, P20 opens.
In both cases it is not seeing the correct value in the P10 hidden item.

I'm assuming this is because I need to put a submit page in when the the button is pressed before opening P20?

If I put a submit page action in, then the modal window appears to open and immediately close ?
If I put submit page into my javascript then the same thing happens.

Can anyone tell me what the right approach is to this ?

with edit button, set item on P10, open P20, query and populate P20 items based on the P10 value
with new button, set to item on P10 to NULL, open P20, set items on P20 to NULL

is what I'm trying to achieve.

Going slightly mad trying to achieve it!

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Ok got there in the end, use

BEGIN
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P20_JOB_ID',:P10_SCHEDULER_ACTION_JOB_ID);
END;

To pass the value from P10 to P20 items.